# Tuleap - Ldap user mail id change

Tags: php, email, ldap, tuleap

I have integrated Tuleap with LDAP and i have imported some 470 users into the project and i have manually created 23 users. The problem is that users called via LDAP are not able to change their mail address, real-name and password. But users who are manually created can change their mail id, real-name and password. Is there a way, whether users called via LDAP can change their mail address and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuleap consider the LDAP server as the one true reference, hence will not allow to change password locally.

The only possibility would be to allow Tuleap to write LDAP passwords but:

- this feature is not in production yet (however there are some code that somewhat do that in draft on gerrit)
- it would imply to grant Tuleap server write access to the reference LDAP.

For the latter I don't know any sysadmin who would be keen to let an application to write in "his" LDAP.